# How to preprocess the username in Symfony Security

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I am using Symfony Security for the login functionality. My username field is encrypted in the database and I guess that Symfony Security is not able to find the correct user when logging in, because of that.

Currently I have an empty login action, which it says in the docs that I should have:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
}
```

I wonder if I could in some way encrypt the username in the request before sending it to Symfonys bundled login method. I guess that I have to extend this loginAction in some way? Or is it just overridden by Symfony?

Comment: Why do you encrypt it in the very first place?

Comment: It is already encrypted by mysql using AES_ENCRYPT which I am not in charge of. I agree with you about that...

Answer (score 0):

use a [custom provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-provider) to encrypte $username before you search User entity with username